# iOS app is crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem in my code that I can't figure out. When I run my app, sometimes it loads my cell, sometimes it crashes immediately. I believe my problem is with my `cellForRowInIndexPath`.

My error is in the line of `cellForRowInIndexPath`:

```
cellDrawer.insertDescriptionLabel(cell, text: offer.title)
```

This is my error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)
```

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ProdutsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchResultsUpdating{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewFooter: MyFooter!

    var searchResults:[Offer] = []
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
    var loading = false


    lazy var offers:[Offer]? = {
        print("lazy of offers\n")
        var restConnection = RestFulConnection()
        restConnection.fetchDataFromServer()
        return DataBaseChecker.getDataFromDatabase()
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewDidLoad\n")
        self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

            return controller
        })()

        // Reload the table
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        self.tableViewFooter.hidden = true

        loadSegment()
    }

    class MyDataProvider {

        class func getInstance() -> MyDataProvider {
            print("getInstance of MyDataProvider\n")
            return MyDataProvider() //return a new instance since class vars not supported yet
        }

        func requestData(listener:([Offer]) -> ()) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                //simulate delay
                sleep(1)
                print("requestData of MyDataProvider\n")
                //generate items

                var restConnection = RestFulConnection()
                restConnection.fetchDataFromServer()
                var arr = DataBaseChecker.getDataFromDatabase()

                //call listener in main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    listener(arr)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("scrollViewDidScroll\n")
        let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

        if (maximumOffset - currentOffset) <= 40 {
            print("IF of scrollViewDidScroll\n")
            loadSegment()
        }
    }

    func loadSegment() {
        print("loadSegment\n")
        if (!self.loading) {

            self.setLoadingState(true)
            print("IF of loadSegment\n")

            MyDataProvider.getInstance().requestData(
                {(offers:[Offer]) -> () in
                    print("block of requestData on method loadSegment\n")
                    for offer:Offer in offers {
                        print("for of loadSegment\n")
                        if(DataBaseChecker.isItNew(offer)){
                        self.offers?.append(offer)
                        }
                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    self.setLoadingState(false)
            })
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        print("didReceiveMemoryWarning\n")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        print("CellForRowAtIndexPath\n")
//        var offer:Offer?
//            if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
//                offer = searchResults[indexPath.row]
//            } else {
//                offer = offers?[indexPath.row]
//            }
        if(offers != nil){
            var offer:Offer = offers![indexPath.row]
            print("IF of offers not nil, offers = \(offer.title)\n")
                var cellDrawer = CellDrawer()
                if (cell.viewWithTag(1) == nil){
                    cellDrawer.createWhiteContentInCell(cell)
                }
                cellDrawer.insertImageInCell(offer.images, cell: cell)
                cellDrawer.insertBlackContentInCell(cell)
                cellDrawer.insertDescriptionLabel(cell, text: offer.title)
                cellDrawer.insertLocalLabel(cell, text: "String Sample")
                cellDrawer.insertOldPriceLabel(cell, number: offer.oldPrice)
                //cellDrawer.insertFromPriceLabel(cell, text: "a partir de")
                cellDrawer.insertNewPriceLabel(cell,number:offer.newPrice)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("NumberOfRowsInSection\n")
        if(offers != nil){
            print("IF offers not nil of NumberOfRowsInSection\n")
            if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
                print("IF2 of NumberOfRowsInSection\n")
                return searchResults.count
            } else {
                print("ELSE of NumberOfRowsInSection, offers count = \(offers!.count)\n")
                return offers!.count
            }
        }
        return 0
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("numberOfSectionsInTableView\n")
        if(offers != nil && offers!.count >= 1){
            print("if of numberOfSectionsInTableView\n")
                return 1
        }
        return 0
    }

    func setLoadingState(loading:Bool) {
        print("setLoadingState\n")
        self.loading = loading
        self.tableViewFooter.hidden = !loading
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        print("heightForRowAtIndexPath\n")
        return 235
    }


    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        print("updateSearchResultsForSearchController\n")
        if(offers != nil){
            print("if of updateSearchResultsForSearchController")
            searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
            let array = NSArray(array: offers!)
            array.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
            self.searchResults = array as! [Offer]

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
       print("prepareForSegue\n")
        if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {
            print("IF of prepareForSegue\n")
            let DetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsTVC
            if sender as! UITableView == self.resultSearchController.active {
                print("IF2 of prepareForSegue\n")
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
                let offer = self.searchResults[indexPath.row]
                DetailTVC.offer = offer
            } else {
                print("Else of prepareForSegue\n")
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
                let offer = self.offers![indexPath.row]
                DetailTVC.offer = offer
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope anyone may help.

Comment: This is the git of the project: https://github.com/nunesdennis/feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If offer.title is not nil, then possibly the cellDrawer is executing something on a cell that is no longer valid.

Set a breakpoint and check the offer.title property using po (print object) in the debugger.

It could also be a race condition that the offer array is being updated while the drawer is trying to load the title.

Comment: When I printed, it returned the title of the offer, and stopped because of the breakpoint.

Comment: Try if let offer = offers![indexPath.row]{ // do the work here }

Comment: I have a print in every method, the last two methods are: CellForRowAtIndexPath
requestData of MyDataProvider
maybe it is what you said...

Comment: Also, could you post some of the stack trace please?

Comment: Those are the last methods :
**numberOfSectionsInTableView;**
if of numberOfSectionsInTableView;
**NumberOfRowsInSection;**
IF offers not nil of NumberOfRowsInSection;
ELSE of NumberOfRowsInSection, offers count = 1;
**heightForRowAtIndexPath;**
**scrollViewDidScroll;**
**scrollViewDidScroll;**
**heightForRowAtIndexPath;**
**CellForRowAtIndexPath;**
OfferTitle;

Comment: if let offer = offers![indexPath.row]{  //cell drawing code } gave an error: bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you register the class for for the reuse identifier. In your viewDidLoad function there should be:

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think offer itself is nil, and you get the crash when you try and get the title property/ivar.

Comment: I can print the offer.title, I don't know if it gets nil somehow later though

Comment: I assume you're stepping through and seeing the error at the line: cellDrawer.insertDescriptionLabel(cell, text: offer.title);  Put a breakpoint on that line, and, in the debugger console, type the following 'po cellDrawer', 'po cell', and 'po offer'.  That might help you figure out which is the bad object reference.

Comment: When I tried Po cellDrawer + offer everything was fine....when I tried Po cellDrawer + offer.title, title didn't print...even though it has a title according  to the last PO of offer on the first try....when I tried Po cellDrawer, Cell, Offer....I got cellDrawer Fine, Cell fine, and offer:<Offer: 0x7fa559dbd230> (entity: Offer; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://71D9ADA7-A4AA-445B-8654-E22CAD6C1F4E/Offer/p1> ; data: <fault> )

Comment: With the same Po, I tried again and those 3 objects were not nil/empty... -.-

Comment: You're getting 'offer' out of the array 'offers'. Maybe some rows are there, and you are accessing beyond what the number of rows actually is?  Make sure that for the number of rows you say you have in the section, there are an equal number of items in the array 'offers'.

Comment: I tried to get 0 instead of indexPath.row, and tried using 1 in number of rows and sections, didn't work sadly

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very similar issue with the same error. Finally I've founded the mistake, and it was because a @IBOutlet of a custom class (MyMapView class). When using custom classes in UI it needs to indicate the class in the Identity Inspector of the Interface Builder. It solved my case.

[image]